# R: Diagnostic Tests on Panel Regression

Tags: r, panel, diagnostics, plm

I have the following [data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/108michael/ms_thesis/master/femodel.csv) that I am running panel regression on. I would like to test for unit root using `plm`'s `purtest`:

```
    date    years_exp   cid cfcontrol   leg_totalbills  state   amtsumlag_1 amtsumfwd_1 billsumfwd_1    billsum amtsum  unemplag_1  logleg_totalbills   logamtsumlag_1  logamtsumfwd_1  logamtsum   exp_5_9 exp_10_19   exp20   post2009years   amtsum_5to9exp  amtsum_10to19exp    amtsum_exp20    amtsumlag1_5to9exp  amtsumlag1_10to19exp    amtsumlag1_exp20    amtsumfwd1_5to9exp  amtsumfwd1_10to19exp    amtsumfwd1_exp20    amtsum_post2009years    amtsumfwd1_post2009years    amtsumlag1_post2009years    logamtsum_5to9exp   logamtsum_10to19exp logamtsum_exp20 logamtsumlag1_5to9exp   logamtsumlag1_10to19exp logamtsumlag1_exp20 logamtsumfwd1_5to9exp   logamtsumfwd1_10to19exp logamtsumfwd1_exp20 logamtsum_post2009years logamtsumfwd1_post2009years logamtsumlag1_post2009years
1   2006    18  N00007665   0   2   HI  309 376.54  1   0   286.139 2.9 0.6931472   5.733341    5.931024    5.656478    0   1   0   2006    0   286.139 0   0   309 0   0   376.54  0   573994.8    755339.2    619854  0   5.656478    0   0   5.733341    0   0   5.931024    0   11346.89    11897.63    11501.08
2   2008    20  N00007665   0   2   HI  376.54  13.66   2   0   334.095 2.8 0.6931472   5.931024    2.614472    5.811425    0   0   1   2008    0   0   334.095 0   0   376.54  0   0   13.66   670862.8    27429.28    756092.3    0   0   5.811425    0   0   5.931024    0   0   2.614472    11669.34    5249.859    11909.5
3   2006    24  N00001143   0   2   NY  124.763 140.755 1   0   197.874 5   0.6931472   4.826416    4.947021    5.28763 0   0   1   2006    0   0   197.874 0   0   124.763 0   0   140.755 396935.2    282354.5    250274.6    0   0   5.28763 0   0   4.826416    0   0   4.947021    10606.99    9923.724    9681.79
4   2008    26  N00001143   0   22  NY  140.755 151.65  0   0   243.545 4.6 3.091042    4.947021    5.021575    5.495302    0   0   1   2008    0   0   243.545 0   0   140.755 0   0   151.65  489038.4    304513.2    282636  0   0   5.495302    0   0   4.947021    0   0   5.021575    11034.57    10083.32    9933.618
5   2010    28  N00001143   0   9   NY  151.65  138.25  0   0   194.317 8.3 2.197225    5.021575    4.929064    5.269491    0   0   1   1   0   0   194.317 0   0   151.65  0   0   138.25  194.317 138.25  151.65  0   0   5.269491    0   0   5.021575    0   0   4.929064    5.269491    4.929064    5.021575
```

I run the following code for unit root using the `hadri, madwu, ips, and levinlin` tests. :

`purtest(billsum~trend,  data = femodel_1,  index=c('date', 'cid'), pmax = 2, exo = "trend", test = "hadri")`

and get the following error:

`Error in data.frame(`2005`= structure(c(333L, 333L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 51, 378, 41, 439, 63, 438, 42, 432, 93, 441`

Does anyone have an idea of what might be the problem?

Comment: The issue of unbalanced panel data is addressed in version 2.2-2 of plm on CRAN. The tests of Hadri and of Levin/Lin/Chu are not applicable to unbalanced data, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hadri LM test for panel unit roots is not applicable to unbalanced panels.

Comment: It is also giving me the same errors for the `hadri, madwu, ips, and levinlin tests`.

Comment: @MichaelPerdue You might want to take a look at this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/44179/8141